# MappingModel valueExpression is null despite filling it in

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I am at a loss as to why my valueExpression in my NSPropertyMapping during migration is null. I have made sure that the value expression is not null in my Mapping Model and I am unsure what else to do to solve this issue.

Would someone be able to please kindly point me in the right direction to solving this problem?

```
"(NSPropertyMapping), name creationDate, valueExpression (null), userInfo (null)",
"(NSPropertyMapping), name lastModifiedDate, valueExpression (null), userInfo (null)"

relationshipMappings (
"(NSPropertyMapping), name assignedProfessor, valueExpression (null), userInfo (null)",
"(NSPropertyMapping), name enrolledStudents, valueExpression (null), userInfo (null)" )
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because these are unchanged? You could test by changing the name of one of them and seeing if the value expressions show up.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. You are correct that in this situation I did not change the attributes. I will test your hypothesis and report back with the results when I get the chance to. Thanks!

Comment: @Mundi So your hypothesis is incorrect. Thanks for trying

Comment: Are you sure it is reading and using *your* migration policies, and not the "inferred" ones?

Comment: @Mundi that is an interesting thought. How would I determine that?

Comment: @JasperChan you can determine relatioship's values in custom migration policy. The instance has `func createRelationships(forDestination dInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws`. To assign custom policy class you can use mappingmodel UI. Here is [some info](http://mikeglukhov.blogspot.ru/2017/01/couldnt-create-mapping-policy-for-class.html) about that.